# cannot find symbol in constructor Service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

I try to compile a webservice project in Eclipse with JavaSE 1.6.

In the project I use a lot of classes created from WSDL.

```
The error message is:

cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
    [javac] location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
```

The source code (the compiled class from WSDL:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */

.....

    public IfaceService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
       **super(__getWsdlLocation(), IFACESERVICE_QNAME, features);**
    }


I read in another tread there are problems with JAX-WS version 2.1 in some cases. Therefore I tried different versions in the ivy config file.

    <info organisation="de.os.osvk.ech" module="my Project"
        status="integration" revision="0.1">
    </info>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.inject.extensions" name="guice-servlet" rev="3.0"/>

        <dependency org="org.glassfish.ha" name="ha-api" rev="3.1.8">
            <artifact name="ha-api" ext="jar" type="jar"/>
            <exclude org="com.sun.enterprise" module="hk2"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="com.sun.xml.ws" name="jaxws-tools" rev="2.2.7"/> 
        <dependency org="javax.ws.rs" name="jsr311-api" rev="1.1.1"/>
        <dependency org="com.sun.jersey" name="jersey-core" rev="1.7" />
        <dependency org="javax.transaction" name="jta" rev="1.1"/>
        <dependency org="javax.xml.ws" name="jaxws-api" rev="2.1.1"></dependency>
        <dependency org="org.quartz-scheduler" name="quartz" rev="1.7.3" conf="*->*,!sources">
            <exclude org="javax.ejb" />
            <exclude org="javax.mail" />
            <exclude org="javax.servlet" />
            <exclude org="org.apache.openejb" />
            <exclude org="junit" />
            <exclude org="javax.jms" /> 
        </dependency> 

        <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.7.1"/>
        <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty" name="jetty-servlet" rev="7.4.4.v20110707"/>
    </dependencies> 
</ivy-module>
```

Which versions of `javax.xml.ws or jaxax.xml.binding` I have to use zu compile against `JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01 (Java code from WSDL)`?

Answer (score 0):

`dependency org="javax.xml.ws" name="jaxws-api" rev="2.1.1"` is suspicious - you probably need 2.2.x. However, Java SE 6 includes an old version of the JAX-WS API. You might need to read https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use jdk1.6.0_35 to generate WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Adding *webservices-api-2.2.jar* alone in **%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed** has resolved issue for me.